# AutoExec Module not Initiating

Tags: ms-access, module, vba

My data storage form has a new module (AutoExec) which is meant to test the connection to a SQL server db upon opening the form. Only it is not firing when opened. I was wondering if there was something in my code causing this, this is my first Module so I am not familiar with the proper forms yet.

```
Public Sub AutoExec()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim localrst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim remoterst As New ADODB.Recordset

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=DB\P003,49503; Initial Catalog=HRLearnDev;" _
    & "User Id=USERNAME; Password=PASSWORD;"

If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then

    MsgBox ("You have an established connection.")
  Else
    MsgBox ("Cannot connect to remote server. Data will be stored locally  to CDData Table until application is opened again.")

End If

cnn.Close
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset


End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a code that calls Sub? You need to call a sub in order to execute it unless it's a built in event procedure

Comment: How would I write that in?

Comment: you should use the following form event: `Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)`

Comment: Still didn't work, when I open the DB and there is a connection to the server, which I am always connected to. I am supposed to get the message box You Have an Established Connection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a database includes a macro named *AutoExec*, Access will run that macro at database startup.

In order for that to work, *AutoExec* must be an Access *macro object*.  In your case, you have a VBA procedure named *AutoExec*.  Since that is not a *macro object*, Access does not run the procedure automatically at database startup.

I suggest you create a VBA function ...

```vb
Public Function Startup()
```

Add the code from the body of your *AutoExec* procedure to the function.

Then create a new Access macro (an actual Access macro object --- on the ribbon in Access 2007, choose *Create->Macro*), use the macro `RunCode` action to run your new `Startup()` function.  Name that macro object as *AutoExec*.

Here is a screenshot of my simple *AutoExec* example macro open in Design View.

[image: AutoExec macro in design view]

Comment: So how would I set it up as a macro object?

Comment: I added instructions.

Comment: Were you able to create the macro object?

Comment: No, like I said this is all very new to me.

Comment: OK, find the "Create" section on the ribbon.  Then choose "Macro" from the "Macro" drop down.  If you get lost, better tell us your Access version.  If it's <= 2003, you need a different approach to create the macro.

Comment: The connector test is working, the only issue now is if it doesn't connect the proper message isn't showing up. I tried a TRY CATCH but it didn't tell me anything. ANy more thoughts?

Comment: I didn't actually look at that code in detail before.  You're testing a connection, so shouldn't need recordsets at all, but I doubt that is relevant.  I think you should break that out as a new question because it really has nothing to do with AutoExec.  Indicate whether you get an error message when the connection attempt fails.

Comment: The testing is only one part of it, the recordsets are for part 2. IF there is a connection then the data stored on a local table is supposed to write to the sql server db.